# Pell's equation solution set

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, square-numbers

Can we guarantee that pell equation has infinitely many solutions in positive integers without finding a non trivial solution?

Comment: One can **prove** that Pell's equation has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: A solution in integers to the Pell equation $x^2-Dy^2=1$,$D>0$, $D$ integer, $\sqrt D\not\in\Bbb Z$, induces a unit $x\pm y\sqrt D$ in the ring $R$ of integers of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt D]$. (Which is $\Bbb Z[\sqrt D]$ or slightly bigger.) We have *general* theorems about (the torsion part and) the rank of the unit group $R^\times$ of the integers $R$ of a number field, this is in terms of number of pair of complex conjugated, respectively purely real embeddings of $R$ in $\Bbb C$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem . For Pell  $(r_1,r_2)=(2,0)$. If  fundamental unit $u$, $u^2$...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $$  x^2 - n y^2 = 1, $$
with fixed integer $n > 0$ but NOT an integer square, then yes, infinitely many solutions in a Fibonacci type sequence.

It is a non-trivial result that there is at least one solution, take the smallest integers $u,v > 0$ with $u^2 - n v^2 = 1.$ Call $(u,v)$ the **fundamental** solution.

The automorphism generator matrix is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & nv \\
v & u
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which means $$ (x_{k+1}, y_{k+1}) = (u x_k + nv y_k \; , \; \; v x_k + u y_k) . $$
The sequences can be separated, $x_0 = 1, y_0 = 0,$ then $x_1 = u, y_1 = v,$ then
$$  x_{k+2} = 2u x_{k+1} - x_k \; ,  $$
$$  y_{k+2} = 2u y_{k+1} - y_k \; ,  $$